# git clone remote to remote without local copy

Tags: git, git-clone

I want to clone from a remote A, and I want to push the clone to another remote B. I'm aware I can do this with 2 lines to have a bare clone from A to local and push to remote B.

Is this also possible without a local intermediate clone (similar to how we can pipe output from a first shell command directly to second shell command)?

Impersonation on the first remote via SSH shell or similar tricks are not possible for my scenario.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no easy way to do that, You can try to manipulate [git-fetch-pack](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-fetch-pack) and pipe the bundle into [git-send-pack](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-send-pack) but your use case is not what these plumbing programs are intended for hence no simple way.